# Convert subselection of TTree to array of floats in CERN's ROOT

Tags: arrays, root-framework

How can I convert data from TTree into array of floats in [CERN's ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/)? I need only part of data and now I can draw this part using [TTree:Draw](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TTree.html#TTree%3aDraw@2) (with both 'varexp', and ' selection' options). My task is to get data which was drawed as array. I would like to get this data as C array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at TTree::GetV1().

For example

```
TTree *t = ... ; // assume you got your tree somewhere
int sz = t->Draw("val", "cuts");
Double_t *vars = t->GetV1();
for ( int i = 0; i < sz; ++i ) {
  cout << vars[i] << endl;
}
```

You can confirm that this works by comparing the output with TTree::Scan.